# How to specify Security Group when creating VPC in AWS web console UI

Tags: amazon-vpc, security-groups, aws-vpc

I created a security group and then wanted to create a VPC and specify this VPC to use this existing security group.  I couldn't find an option in AWS' current  VPC form to specify the security group.  Is it possible to specify the security group in the creation form for a VPC or do I have to use Terraform/cloud formation?

The region is eu-west-2 in case that's important.

Motivation:
Without being able to specify the security group to use, AWS automatically creates a default security group. These "default" security groups do not appear to be deletable and as I am unexperienced and learning/experimenting I now have 5 default, unused and seemingly undeletable security groups.  I am concerned that these will just keep multiplying and render the security groups list increasingly harder to use for myself and the client's team.  AWS suggest you keep security groups to a minimum as to avoid mistakes but I can't figure out how to avoid AWS automatically creating a new undeletable default security group every time I want to create a new VPC.

Thank you in advance.

** edit **
Default security groups are not deletable but if all the resources they are associated with are removed then it appears AWS automatically deletes them.